# Function Inside Subscription - Angular 4

Tags: angular, rest, model-view-controller, subscription

I'm having an issue calling a function within a subscription. In this function, I call a subscription that refreshes a token, if this returns "true" I then call the same function but this operation does not work.

Main function:

```
 getLicenseList():Observable<License[]>{
    let licenseList:License[] =[];
    return this._http.get("license/list").map(res => {
        let processedData = res;
        if(processedData['status'] == "401"){
            this._http.refreshToken().subscribe(result => {
                this.getLicenseList();
            });
        }else{
            for(let license of processedData['data']){
                const obj = new License(license['name'],license['start_date'],license['expire_date'], license['type'], license['duration'],license['id'],license['id_user'], license['projectsList']);
                licenseList.push(obj);
            }
            return licenseList;
        }
    });

}
```

Function for refresh token:

```
refreshToken():Observable<boolean>{
    let url = 'auth/refresh/self';
    return this.post(url, localStorage.getItem('refresh_token')).map(data => {
        if(data['access_token'] != null || data['refresh_token'] != null){
            window.localStorage.setItem('access_token', data['access_token']);
            window.localStorage.setItem('refresh_token', data['refresh_token']);
            return true;
        }
    }).catch(error =>Observable.throw("Expired refresh token"));
}
```

in debug mode into the res can I see: "Unexpected end of input"

Comment: `getLicenseList` will always return `licenseList`, as the other return statement depends on an async operation

Answer (score 0):

You can use flapMap to merge observables

```
 return http.get(req1)
      .flatMap(resp => {
        // whatever you need
        return this.http.post(req2);
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
getLicenseList():Observable<License[]>{
    let licenseList:License[] =[];
    return this._http.get("license/list").map(async res =>{
            let processedData = res;
            if(processedData['status'] == "401"){
                this._http.refreshToken().subscribe(result =>{ if(result){ return this.getLicenseList();} });
            else{
            for(let license of processedData['data']){
                const obj = new License(license['name'],license['start_date'],license['expire_date'], license['type'], license['duration'],license['id'],license['id_user'], license['projectsList']);
                licenseList.push(obj);
            }
            return licenseList;
        }
    });

}
```

I see you are passing in a bunch of variable to the constructor. I recommend passing the whole object and having the constructor take care of the parsing. 
Use async and await inside of the observable to make things wait. 
Other than that great code!!